# PHP: create array from arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form that is posting 4 arrays that I need to combine and eventually compose to email. The four arrays:

```
$quantityArray    = $this->input->post('qty');
$dimensionArray   = $this->input->post('dimension');
$thicknessArray   = $this->input->post('thickness');
$descriptionArray = $this->input->post('description');
```

will all have the same array length and each index will be related. How do I combine the 4 arrays such as

```
[0]
     'qty' => '1',
     'dimenesion => '2x2',
     'thickness' => '2in',
     'description' => 'this is the description'
[1]
     'qty' => '1',
     'dimenesion => '2x2',
     'thickness' => '2in',
     'description' => 'this is the description'
```

I have tried array_combined, array_merged and can't get the results that I am looking for. Thanks for the help on this.

Comment: A simple loop can do this.

Comment: BTW, how do you expect the resulting array ? Both arrays look same.

Comment: sorry, just copied and pasted the example result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have same length for those arrays here is example code:

```
$resultArray = array();
foreach($quantityArray as $index => $qty) {
    $resultArray[$index]['qty'] = $qty;
    $resultArray[$index]['dimenesion'] = $dimensionArray[$index];
    $resultArray[$index]['thickness'] = $thicknessArray[$index];
    $resultArray[$index]['description'] = $descriptionArray [$index];
}

print_r($resultArray);
```

Comment: very clean and concise. Thanks for the help on this one!

Answer (score 1):

This also may work:

```
<?php
//...
$quantityArray    = $this->input->post('qty');
$dimensionArray   = $this->input->post('dimension');
$thicknessArray   = $this->input->post('thickness');
$descriptionArray = $this->input->post('description');

//
// combine them:
//
$combined = array();
$n = count($quantityArray);
for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
{
  $combined[] = array(
    'qty' => $quantityArray[$i],
    'dimenesion' => $dimensionArray[$i],
    'thickness' => $thicknessArray[$i],
    'description' => $descriptionArray[$i]
  );
}
//
echo "<pre>";
print_r($combined);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that we have same length for those arrays here is my codes:

```
$quantityArray = array(1, 1, 5, 3);
$dimensionArray = array("2x2", "3x3", "4x4", "2x2");
$thicknessArray = array("2in", "3in", "4in", "2in");
$descriptionArray = array("this is the description 1", "this is the description 2 ", "this is the description3 ", "this is the description4" );

$myCombinArray = array();
foreach ( $quantityArray as $idx => $val ) {
    $subArray = array (
            'qty' => $quantityArray [$idx],
            'dimenesion' => $dimensionArray [$idx],
            'thickness' => $thicknessArray [$idx],
            'description' => $descriptionArray [$idx] 
    );
    array_push ( $myCombinArray, $subArray );
}
print_r($myCombinArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about an easy way if there are always those 4 arrays:

```
$quantityArray    = $this->input->post('qty');
$dimensionArray   = $this->input->post('dimension');
$thicknessArray   = $this->input->post('thickness');
$descriptionArray = $this->input->post('description');

$combinedArray = [$quantityArray, $dimensionArray, $thicknessArray, $descriptionArray];

# old syntax:
# $combinedArray = array($quantityArray, $dimensionArray, $thicknessArray, $descriptionArray);
```